# image of complex continuous function cannot be a curve

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $ f : U \subset \mathbb C \to \mathbb C $ a continuous function where $ U $ is an open and connected set.

Prove that the image of $ f$ **cannot** be a curve on compex plane.

Comment: False without further conditions on $f$.  Is $f$ analytic? Injective?  Either would be sufficient.

Comment: @ErickWong: I found this exercise exactly as I post it. Can you give your solution with the further conditions ?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/44757/8157 (this requires analyticity of $f$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure there are no additional constraints, e.g. the Cauchy-Riemann equations are satisfied (continuity + C.R. -> analytic). One could simply take $f(z) = \Re(z)$, which is continuous but not analytic -- the image of an open set (say the ball of radius 1 around the origin) is a curve (the interval $[-1,1]$).

The reason this cannot hold for an analytic function is because of the open mapping theorem. Analytic functions are open mappings, so an open set $U$ has to map to an open set $f(U)$, which cannot be a curve.

Comment: O.K I see thank you very much! Can we find an example of a non-analytic function for which the claim fails ?

Comment: Yes, $f(z) = \Re(z)$, as stated. The important thing to understand is that a curve is not open in the topology of $\mathbb{R}^2$.